# Javascript or Jquery rounding up to 1 decimal place

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, rounding

I need to round up to 1 decimal place

If my number is 80.02 I need it to be 80.1.

tried

```
Math.ceil( (80.02).toFixed(1) ) but this rounds the number up to 81
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil

Answer (score 9):

use `Math.ceil( number * 10 ) / 10;` for rounding off

for fixing it to one decimal place

`(Math.ceil( number * 10 ) / 10).toFixed(1);`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Da9tz/)**

Answer (score 2):

I think it should work perfectly:

```
parseFloat(13.2*13.23).toFixed(1)
```

output:174.6

for your 80.02 - 80.0 and for 80.06-80.1 which is good

Answer (score -1):

you should use floor instead of ceil

```
Math.floor( (80.02).toFixed(1) )
```

Answer (score -1):

Math.round will round up at >= x.5  and round down at < x.5

.ceil  round up to the next number

.floor round down to the next number

Comment: So what would make it round to 80.1?